# Parse static HTML file with Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

So I have a static HTML file somewhere on my hard drive that I want to extract source code from using Python. I tried the urllib2 but i am getting an error that says urlopen error unknown url type. I am guessing its because my URL was actually a destination on hard drive rather than a valid HTTP address. How can i extract that code? Here's what I tried:

```
import urllib2
url = "C:\Program Files\Whatever Folder\Whatever.html"
file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = file.read()

OUT = data
```

Comment: try `file://C:/Program Files/Whatever Folder/Whatever.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the built-in [open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) function e.g:

```
url = "C:\Program Files\Whatever Folder\Whatever.html"
with open(url, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

You could also use some library to help you parse the html e.g. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: I got the parsing part figured out. I was actually using beautiful soup for it, however I was always converting my files to TXT from HTML. I want to eliminate that step. Thank you!